# Prove a function's injectivity and surjectivity

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Good day all! 
I am new to set theory and I need some help on the question.
Can anyone show me how to start this proof?

Problem:

Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of a set $E$.
Let $f$ be a mapping from $\mathcal P(E)$ to $\mathcal P(A) \times \mathcal P(B)$
be defined by $f(X)=(A \cap X, B \cap X)$.

a) Show $f$ is injective iff $A \cup B = E$.

b) show $f$ is surjective iff $A \cap B = \varnothing$.

Any help would be appreciated. The thing that is messing me up is the function - im not use to this type of notation. Im comfortable with something like $f(x)=2x+1$ but im confused on how the function above "works" I guess.

Comment: Good that you identified the problem! Work this example: Let $E=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, $A=\{1,2\}, B=\{4,5\}$. Now pick a few elements of $P(E)$, which are subsets of $E$, and identify their images in $P(A)\times P(B)$. Check back if you like.

Comment: Trying to figure out what your problem with the definition is: Would you be comfortable with "Let $a$ and $b$ be numbers and let $g$ be the function defined by $g(x)=ax^2+b\sqrt x$"? Would you be comfortable with "Let $h$ be the function from $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ to $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$ defined by $h(X)= (X\cap [10,20])\cup(1,2]$"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one direction of part a).

Suppose $A\cup B=E$, then for any $X\subseteq E$, $X=(A\cap X)\cup (B\cap X)$.

If $f(X)=f(Y)$ then $(A\cap X,B\cap X)=(A\cap Y,B\cap Y)$ which implies $A\cap X=A\cap Y$ and $B\cap X=B\cap Y$. So,

$$X=(A\cap X)\cup(B\cap X)=(A\cap Y)\cup(B\cap Y)=Y.$$

Hopefully this will get you thinking along the right track.

Comment: Thanks Tim , this is perfect! It makes sense. Ill try doing a similar process witht the second one...

Answer (score 1):

Hints on a)

- If $A\cup B\neq E$ then $E-(A\cup B)$ has more than one subset. These are all mapped to?
- If $A\cup B = E$ then $X=(A\cap X)\cup(B\cap X)$

Hint on b)

- If $A\cap B=\varnothing$ then $X=A_0\cup B_0$ where $A_0\subseteq A$ and $B_0\subseteq B$ is sent to?...
- If $x\in A\cap B$ then can you find a set $X$ such that $x$ in element of exactly one of the sets $A\cap X$ and $B\cap X$?

Comment: hmm..I know what you mean for part B. It will turn out that no such x exists  (the set X would be the null set) but im no sure how to start it. Any suggestions?

Comment: So no $X$ exists that is sent e.g. to the pair $\langle\{x\},\varnothing\rangle$, justifying the conclusion that $f$ is not surjective. Proved is now: $A\cap B\neq\varnothing\implies f\text{ is not surjective}$

Answer (score 1):

First part:

$A \cup B=E \Rightarrow f$ is injective.

Suppose that $f(A_1)=f(A_2)$ for some $A_1,A_2 \in \mathcal{P}(E)$. We have to prove that $A_1=A_2$. But:

$$f(A_1)=(A_1 \cap A, A_1 \cap B)$$
$$f(A_2)=(A_2 \cap A, A_2 \cap B)$$

So:

$$A_1 \cap A=A_2 \cap A$$

and

$$A_1 \cap B = A_2 \cap B$$

So:

$$(A_1 \cap A) \cup (A_1 \cap B)=(A_2 \cap A) \cup (A_2 \cap B)$$

But we can check that if $A \cup B=E$, then:

$$(A_1 \cap A) \cup (A_1 \cap B)=A_1$$
$$(A_2 \cap A) \cup (A_2 \cap B)=A_2$$

Finally $A_1=A_2$.

$f$ is injective $\Rightarrow A \cup B=E$.

Suppose that there exists $x \in E$ such that $x \not\in A \cup B$. Then $f(\{x\})=f(\emptyset)$ because:

$$f(\emptyset)=(\emptyset \cap A,\emptyset \cap B)=(\emptyset,\emptyset)$$

and because $x \not \in A \cup B$ then $x \not \in A$ and $x \not \in B$, so:

$$f(\{x\})=(\{x\} \cap A,\{x\} \cap B)=(\emptyset,\emptyset)$$

Could you try do similar think with second part?

Comment: Hey agha, thanks so much for this. It really helped me out. Ive tried to start the second part, but Im running into trouble. Do you have any pointers on how to start it?